# post request using superagent

Tags: node.js, superagent

I have been trying to make a post request to the pokeapi using superagent request lib. I am not sure why the request is not successful. Below is my code. I am fairly new to superagent, so any advice will be appreciated.

```
try {
    const pokemon = await superagent.post(
      `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${req.body.id}`
    );
    console.log(pokemon);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  next();
```

The error listed was:

```
error: Error: cannot POST /api/v2/pokemon/1 (404)
        at Response.toError (G:\CodersArts\pokemon-app\pokemonapi\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\response.js:98:13)
        at ResponseBase._setStatusProperties (G:\CodersArts\pokemon-app\pokemonapi\node_modules\superagent\lib\response-base.js:119:48)
        at new Response (G:\CodersArts\pokemon-app\pokemonapi\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\response.js:44:8)
        at Request._emitResponse (G:\CodersArts\pokemon-app\pokemonapi\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:930:18)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (G:\CodersArts\pokemon-app\pokemonapi\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:1127:42)
        at Stream.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at Unzip.<anonymous> (G:\CodersArts\pokemon-app\pokemonapi\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\unzip.js:53:12)
        at Unzip.emit (events.js:327:22)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1220:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
      status: 404,
      text: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' +
        '<html lang="en">\n' +
        '<head>\n' +
        '<meta charset="utf-8">\n' +
        '<title>Error</title>\n' +
        '</head>\n' +
        '<body>\n' +
        '<pre>Cannot POST /api/v2/pokemon/1</pre>\n' +
        '</body>\n' +
        '</html>\n',
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/api/v2/pokemon/1'
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? What exactly is not successful?

Comment: I was basically getting a 404. But the api seems to work on their website. I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: The requested `URL` `not found`. Check the `URL` is correct? Request with correct `URL`.

Comment: @RashedRahat eg: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1 is a working url

Comment: It's for `GET` method. Not for `POST`. Check my answer. As a result it's returning `404`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method is incorrect for the requested URL. Use `GET` instead of `POST`.

A sample `GET` request using `superagent`:

```
const nocache = require('superagent-no-cache');
const superagent = require('superagent');
const prefix = require('superagent-prefix')('/static');
 
superagent
  .get('/some-url')
  .query({ action: 'edit', city: 'London' }) // query string
  .use(prefix) // Prefixes *only* this request
  .use(nocache) // Prevents caching of *only* this request
  .end((err, res) => {
    // Do something
  });
```

To know more, visit: [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent)

Comment: yeah right i checked their docs it says it only accepts http requests. Thank youu for your reference